# Proving a Graph (V,E) with a walk can't have a simple path larger than |V| - 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Trying to do some self-study, and the textbook I'm using has a very small set of worked-out review questions. I'm an extreme novice when it comes to proving things, so I'm a little stumped. I've checked Google and past questions, but I can't find a just-right question. Perhaps the wording is a little different, but enough to obscure the right question that has already been asked. Pardon me if it has.

The question is:

Let G = (V, E) be any graph. Prove the following claim: If there is any walk
between v_i ∈ V and v_j ∈ V, then there must be a simple path of length no
larger than | V | − 1 between these two vertices.

Where a walk is a path (v1, v2), (v2, v3) ... (vk, vk+1), and a simple path is a walk that doesn't repeat edges or vertices.

Would this be a proof by induction or contradiction? Just a gentle shove in the direction would probably suffice. If it's induction, would I assume the length of the walk? - but how would that relay into finding a use for a length of "k+1?" Or is it a contradictory proof, where I should assume that there's a simple path of length >= |V|?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

A simple path of length 1 involves two vertices. A simple path of length 2 involves 3 vertices. Can you prove that a simple path of length $k$ involves exactly $k+1$ vertices?

Then, towards a contradiction, say you had a simple walk of length $> |V| - 1$. You would need $> |V|$ vertices - a contradiction.

---

I hope this helps ^_^